# Dynamically allocated arrays and HEAP corrupted

Tags: c++, dynamic-arrays, heap-corruption

I am trying to write a program that takes inputs as a dynamic array and sorts them from lowest to highest and then displays from highest to lowest. However, I get a debugging error that states "HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block (#182) at 0x010CE3E8.
CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer."

Well, the program builds and runs successfully. However, when I try to exit the program it takes a really long time and I receive the error.

```
void insert_Array(int Array1[], int array_size)
{
    for (int counter = 0; counter < array_size; ++counter)
    {
         cout << " Please enter the " << counter << " number : ";
         cin >> Array1[counter];
    }
    return;
}

void swap(int* a, int* b)
{
    int holder = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = holder;
}

void sort_Array(int Array1[], int array_size)
{
    int lowestNum_index;
    for (int counter1 = 0; counter1 < array_size; ++counter1)
    {
        for (int counter2 = counter1; counter2 < array_size; ++counter2)
        {
            if (Array1[counter2] < Array1[counter2 + 1])
                lowestNum_index = counter2;
            else
                lowestNum_index = counter2 + 1;
        }
        swap(Array1[counter1], Array1[lowestNum_index]);
    }
    return;
}
```

Main function

```
int* npointer = new int[nNumbers];
insert_Array(npointer, nNumbers);
sort_Array(npointer, nNumbers);
cout << " The number you desired is " << nNumbers << endl;

cout << " The numbers in the array from  high to low are ";
for (int i = 0; i < nNumbers; ++i)
{
    cout << *(npointer + nNumbers - i) << " ";
}

cout << endl;
delete [] npointer;
```

When I run the program successfully sorts the numbers that I give from highest to lowest.

HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block (#182) at 0x010CE3E8.
CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer.

Comment: ok, I have to ask -- why are you doing all of this when `std::vector` exists, and it has existed for 21+ years in the C++ standard library?  Second, all of the work is inside `insert_Array` and `sort_Array` -- you should have posted that code.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is a homework

Comment: *Well, the program builds and runs successfully* -- It does *not* run successfully.  Please post a [mcve].

Comment: When printing: `*(npointer + nNumbers - i)`, this seems off by one, should be `*(npointer + nNumbers - i - 1)`. Other than that, you don't show what `insert_Array` and `sort_Array` do, so if there's a problem there we won't be able to tell.

Comment: The error is likely caused by writing outside the bounds of the array, as you don't write to the array in the code posted we can't help you, the bug is likely in `insert_Array` or `sort_Array`. Please post a [mre]

Comment: `if (Array1[counter2] < Array1[counter2 + 1])` -- What happens if `counter2` is equal to `array_size - 1`?  See an issue there?

Comment: The sort method seems pretty wrong to me.

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio?  If you are, just for fun, change your `sort_array` function to this: `void sort_Array(int Array_test[], int array_size) {std::vector<int> Array1(Array_test, Array_test + array_size);` and don't change anything else. Run the program using a debug build.  Now watch the errors that the runtime will flag for you.  Once you straighten out those errors, then change back to the array.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie there's nothing wrong with his array init logic, just the sort.

Comment: There is heap corruption, meaning he is corrupting something.  By doing what I suggested, the OP will see for themselves what the error is.  Sometimes not using `std::vector` just makes the job of finding these bugs harder.

Comment: I get no errors @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: @RufatImanov -- Are you using Visual Studio?  There definitely will be an `assert` dialog pop up if you ran the program and used a simple test array such as `{3,2,1}`.  [This example program produces the error in Visual Studio, debug build](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/01592e83b47e6023)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually when doing a nested loop of this kind, the inner loop is set to start at outer loop + 1. So that you don't end up with values like this `Array1[counter2 + 1]` which leads to an illegal memory access outside the bounds of the array on the final iteration of the loop.

Even with that fixed, the sorting logic is incorrect. What you are trying to do is known as a selection sort where you compare each element of the array to the rest of elements in n^2 time complexity. You have to obtain the `lowestNum_index` for each iteration of the outer loop, not the entire array. Here's how I would do a selection sort.

```
void sort_Array(int Array[], int array_size)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < array_size; ++i)
  {
    int lowestIdx = i; // <-- always starts at i
    for (int j = i + 1; j < array_size; ++j)
      if (Array[j] < Array[i])
        lowestIdx = j;

    swap(&Array[lowestIdx], &Array[i]); // <--- note the & symbol to pass by reference
  }
}
```

Since your swap function accepts two pointers, using `Array[i]` will lead to illegal memory access as  the `[]` operator dereferences the array to the value at `i`, you have to use the `&` operator to get the address for that location. i.e.

```
Array[i] = *(Array + i)
&Array[i] = Array + i // <--- essentially cancels the dereference operator
```

**Edit:** Intialize `lowestIdx = i` on each outer loop

Comment: I made a small mistake, fixed.